# How would I return Python dataclass fields/values that are only defined in __post_init__ in print and pd.Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, python-dataclasses

**TL,DR:** I've created a dataclass, where not all fields are defined in the init phase, some get added in `__post_init__` in relation to an InitVar. When I print the class object, only fields in init gets printed but not those added in `__post_init__`.  This is also true if I convert the object to a pandas dataframe (which is what I ultimately would like to achieve). How do I need to change the class code or the print/pandas statements to get all dataclass fields/values?

---

This is an extract of my dataclass definition:

```
@dataclass
class PcpCompound:
    compound: InitVar[Compound] # Compound: class of the pubchempy package
    query_status: str
    query_term: str

    def __post_init__(self, compound: Compound | None):
        if compound is None:
            return
        self.query_finding: str = compound.iupac_name
```

*Results and expectations are shown down below.*

My optimal solution would be to move everything from `__post_init__` to init, but that would require that I check `compound` for None and write all the wanted details from it to their respective fields of the dataclass. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to use `compound` programmaticly in init ... and I believe that this is intended.

If this is not possible, how would I solve this? I would prefer to not define all fields in init, as this is not only tedious and doubles the code amount, but would lead to a lot of 'None' if compound is itself None.

---

The calls to construct an object and to print/convert to a daraframe:

```
PcpCompound = PcpCompound(query_status=status, query_term=query_term, compound=compound)
print(PcpCompound)

PdfCompound = pd.DataFrame([PcpCompound])
print(PdfCompound)
```

Actual output:

```
PcpCompound(query_status='Success!', query_term='someterm')
  query_status query_term
0     Success!   110-89-4
```

Expected output:

```
PcpCompound(query_status='Success!', query_term='110-89-4', query_finding='Piperidine')
  query_status query_term query_finding
0     Success!   110-89-4    Piperidine
```

Note: *All expected values are correctly present in the object, as shown in the VSCode debug view.* This can also be verified by `print(PcpCompound.query_finding)` which returns `Piperidine` as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `query_finding` isn't included in the `print` output or in the DataFrame is because `dataclass` simply isn't aware of your new property, you never told `dataclass` about it (and by extension, pandas).

The solution is to declare your field in the class by using `field(init=False)` to indicate the field cannot be included directly to `__init__` and is instead created in `__post_init__`:

```py
from dataclasses import InitVar, dataclass, field

import pandas as pd


@dataclass
class PcpCompound:
    compound: InitVar[int]  # using `int` for reproducibility
    query_status: str
    query_term: str
    query_finding: str = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self, compound: int) -> None:
        self.query_finding = compound * 2  # pretend this is a real query


c = PcpCompound(compound=123, query_status="Success!", query_term="someterm")
print(c)
print(pd.DataFrame([c]))
```

Output:

```py
PcpCompound(query_status='Success!', query_term='someterm', query_finding=246)
  query_status query_term  query_finding
0     Success!   someterm            246
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... I feared this would be necessary. As my `__post-init__` can be around 40 lines long in the worst case, this leads to a lot of lines of (as I feel unnecessary) additional code. Is there maybe another possible option?

Comment: @MrSiege It would be extremely impractical to do this in any other way. This is the correct way to declare attributes you'll only initialize in `post_init`.

Comment: @MrSiege it's really not clear to me what the problem is exactly. If you want the `dataclasses.dataclass` code generator to generate `__repr__` etc with that attribute, then you *have to tell it about that attribute*. The way to do that is to use annotations. What code, exactly, do you feel is unnecessary? Why is adding a single annotation such a problem?

Comment: @juanpa Not really a problem, more of an inconvenience: With around 40 lines in the `post_init` comes 40 additional lines of annotations. I've hoped that there is a more elegant way. If I could access "compound" programmatically in the annotations section, that would solve my inconvenience, but I don't know how.

Comment: @MrSiege why do you need an annotation for every line in post_init?

Comment: Are you saying your class has 40-odd attributes that only get defined if you pass a compound as an argument? Sounds like your class needs some redesign work.

Comment: I think so too now that I see the limitations of dataclasses regarding my case. I've solved my task with dictionary-based structures until now, found them not pleasing and looked into other solutions. Will search on. Thanks @all for your effort!